# Intent referring to an Inner class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentservice

I want to start an `Intent` with an `AlarmManager` referring to code in an inner class.

My code in MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
[...]
    DataProcessing2 dp = new DataProcessing2();

    startstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v1) {
            if(!listening){
                Log.i("Start","Button Pressed");
                listening = true;
                startstop.setText(R.string.stop);
                dp.start(getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

My code in the DataProcessing2.class

```
public class DataProcessing2 {

public void start_accel(Context context){
    Log.i("Start Accel","Accessed");
    accel.setAccel(context);
    accel.listenAccel();

    Intent getAccelValuesIntent = new Intent(context, DataProcessing2.GetAccelValues.class);
    PendingIntent getValues = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, getAccelValuesIntent, 0);
    getAccelData = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    getAccelData.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), sampling_acc_ms, getValues);
}

public class GetAccelValues extends IntentService {

    public GetAccelValues() {
        super("GetAccelValues");
        }

            [...]

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Acc Values","Intent received");
        accel.calculateAccelerometerData();
        getCalculatedData();
        boolean moving = sD.acc_delta > sD.acc_th;

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("name", "answerAccelerometer");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("moving", moving);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I never get the receive the Intent on GetAccelValues.

Comment: Why would you put a a `Service` inside a POJO? That makes no sense. Also where is your `BroadcastReceiver` which is meant to receive the broadcast you send using `sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);`?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to Execute in the background one function periodically. I don't know if AlarmManager is the best option, but as I thought that would work for me. Is there any better idea @Squonk?

About my Broadcast Receiver it is in the main, but I didn't added as it was not part of the problem. There is some code missing, and I didn't want it to add it all, because it was too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using incompatible clocks. You should either use `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` together with `System.elapsedRealtime()`, or `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` together with `System.currentTimeMillis()`. For example:

```
getAccelData.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        System.currentTimeMillis(), sampling_acc_ms, getValues);
```

Comment: Thanks @bolot, that was the main problem.